# Type mismatch error while adding pivotcache

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

This returns type mismatch error I don't know why.

I asked the same questing yesterday in which I found there were some merged cells hence I removed merge cells today but still it's not working giving the same error

The code works fine with other sheet data but it returns the error for that specific sheet.

I tried this:

```
Set wD = Sheets.Add
ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=wS.UsedRange).CreatePivotTable _
TableDestination:=wD.Range("A3")
```

And this

```
Set wD = Sheets.Add
ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=wS.Range("A1").CurrentRegion).CreatePivotTable _
TableDestination:=wD.Name & "!R3C1"
```

This is what source data sheet looks like

[image: Source Data Sheet]

Comment: if you add `Dim PvtSrcRange  As Range` , then set it to `Set PvtSrcRange = wS.UsedRange` , and then `Debug.Print PvtSrcRange.Address` what do you get in the immediate window ?

Comment: SourceRange is fine Sir. It returned correct range address

Comment: what is your `SourceRange` ? since you are trying to create the `PivotTable` on `Range("A3")` so you might overlap (overwrite) your `SourceRange` data

Comment: No I am creating new worksheet everytime no chance for overlapping.

Comment: Can it be because it has chinese characters in the heading ?

Comment: not sure, I am using Hebrew and it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Sub UpdatePivot()

Dim wD                              As Worksheet
Dim wS                              As Worksheet

Dim PvtTbl                          As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache                        As PivotCache
Dim PvtRangeStr                     As String


Set wS = Sheets("inventory master")
Set wD = Sheets.Add

PvtRangeStr = "'" & wS.Name & "'!" & wS.UsedRange.Address

' for debug
Debug.Print PvtRangeStr

' set Pivot Cache using another reference to the range
Set PvtCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PvtRangeStr, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)    

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PvtTbl = wD.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

On Error GoTo 0
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then

    ' create a new Pivot Table in wD Sheet, start from Cell A3
    Set PvtTbl = wD.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=wD.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTable1")
Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated data
    PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache
    PvtTbl.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I got the same error on `Set PvtCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
SourceData:=wS.UsedRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)`

Comment: @newguy this code was tested and works on my PC. What Excel version are you running ? Did you copy my entire code ?

Comment: Yes entire code wait I will share the workbook in a moment if you like

Comment: Hi did you try it ?

Comment: @newguy i can't from this PC, will try later this evening

Comment: Okay Thank you very much

Comment: @newguy after looking at your code, I found the reason for the error. I modified the code here (not the whole code you sent me) , so try now edited code (I modified the way I reference the Range in the `PivotCache` line)

Comment: Awesome Thank you very much